# SML programming help tuples

Tags: sml, smlnj

```
exception No_intersection of string

fun check_in ((m1:real, b1:real), (m2:real, b2:real)):real*real =
```

The function is supposed to check for an intersection between the two lines. Each pair argument is a slope and a y intercept. I am supposed to find the intersection between the two if it is exists.

I can't make to seem this work for some reason, and have been struggling with this for hours.

Comment: I can not see, how you input your lines. Usually, a line is described by two points or a point and a vector; in any case four scalar values. However, you have four values alltogether.

PS: Homework?

Comment: @Matthias: `m` is the gradient, `b` is the y-intercept.

Comment: @NickBarnes: Of course! I was blind.

Answer (score 1):

Reals are not an equality type in SML, so `(m1-m2) = 0` is a type error.

The reason for this is that the limited precision of floating-point representations can give unexpected results due to rounding errors (e.g. `(1.0/7.7)*7.7 = 1.0` would return `false`). You can get around this by using the `==` operator from the `Real` library, i.e. `Real.==(m1-m2,0)` (or just `Real.==(m1,m2)`). But keep in mind that it can be unreliable.

The second problem is that, according to the return type, your function is supposed to *return* a value, not *print* it. All you need to do here is state the return value in the `else` clause, i.e. just replace `print((x,y))` with `(x,y)`.

And for what it's worth, I'd avoid using exceptions if you can; they kind of go against the idea of functional programming. Try returning a `(real*real) option` instead.